# Cannot access database on the main thread in runnable

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-android-extensions

Room gives error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

Even if I am creating new thread and run query on it, it is giving me above error

My Thread code:

```
val thread = Runnable {
            val intent1 = Intent(activity!!, NewOrderActivity::class.java)
            intent1.putExtra("isReview", isReview)
            intent1.putExtra("editClicked", editClicked)
            intent1.putExtra("orderId", orderId)
            intent1.putExtra(ParamsUtils.connected, CommonUtils.isInNetwork(activity))
            intent1.putExtra("orderName", orderName)
            intent1.putExtra("order", Gson().toJson(orderItem))
            intent1.putExtra("groupId", viewModel.getGroupId(orderItem.buyerId))
            Handler().post {
                startActivity(intent1)
                activity!!.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                activity!!.finish()
            }
        }

        thread.run()
```

Please suggest me where, I am wrong.

**Edit**

I know below way, So please don't comment that.
I don't want to pass activity reference to other class, so I am using thread in same class.

```
internal class NewOrderAsyncTask(activity: Activity, private val isReview: Boolean, private val editClicked: Boolean, private val orderId: Long, private val orderName: String, private val orderItem: OrderItem, private val dataManager: DataManager) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

    //Prevent leak
    private val weakActivity: WeakReference<Activity> = WeakReference(activity)

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): String {
        return dataManager.getGroupId(orderItem.buyerId)
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(agentsCount: String) {
        val activity = weakActivity.get() ?: return

        val intent1 = Intent(activity!!, NewOrderActivity::class.java)
        intent1.putExtra("isReview", isReview)
        intent1.putExtra("editClicked", editClicked)
        intent1.putExtra("orderId", orderId)
        intent1.putExtra(ParamsUtils.connected, CommonUtils.isInNetwork(activity))
        intent1.putExtra("orderName", orderName)
        intent1.putExtra("order", Gson().toJson(orderItem))
        intent1.putExtra("groupId", agentsCount)
        activity.startActivity(intent1)
        activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
        activity.finish()
    }
}
```

1. What is problem with my internal thred?
2. Why gives error, "It is main thread", while I am creating new thread?

Comment: I am not familiar with kotlin, but are you sure you are not declaring a Runnable named thread, instead of actually creating a new Thread with a Runnable inside? In plain java, the thread would be called with start() not run()

Comment: I am creating new thread with Runnable

Comment: It it is a Thread, you should call thread.start() instead or thread.run(). thread.start() will call run() once the new thread is created.

Comment: onPostExecute is done in the main thread, that is why you get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrapped `Runnable` into `Thread`:

```
val intent1 = Intent(activity, NewOrderActivity::class.java).apply {
    putExtra("isReview", isReview)
    putExtra("editClicked", editClicked)
    putExtra("orderId", orderId)
    putExtra(ParamsUtils.connected, CommonUtils.isInNetwork(activity))
    putExtra("orderName", orderName)
    putExtra("order", Gson().toJson(orderItem))
    putExtra("groupId", viewModel.getGroupId(orderItem.buyerId))
}

val thread = Thread(Runnable {
    Handler().post {
        startActivity(intent1)
        activity?.overridePendingTransition(
            android.R.anim.fade_in,
            android.R.anim.fade_out
        )
        activity?.finish()
    }
})

thread.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a new [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread). Instead you created a [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable) and therefore running it means running on the main thread.

Calling the variable 'thread' does not make it a thread of-course. This would make more sense:

```
val runnable = Runnable { //runnable code }
```

Maybe try creating a new thread and overriding the run method(example in java):

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your code
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Comment: but when I use thread or coroutine or async so it used to take bit time so my if else condition failing because I'm checking item is exists or not in db if exists so not store the value if not exists then store the value in DB. how can I get rid from this solution ?

Comment: @Menu this can be done on the thread you create, inside the run method

Comment: My problem has been resolved. I have used  runBlocking {
                val job: Job = launch(context = Dispatchers.Default) {.....} job.join()

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask instead.
e.g.

```
class myTask() : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String? {
        // ...
    }

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
        // ...
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        // ...
    }
}
```

There are several [examples](http://androidpala.com/kotlin-asynctask-android/) around.

**EDIT:** don't know the rest of your code, but try doing your connection in the `doInBackground` part, and then pass the required values of your new activity to the `onPostExequte` part through its params

Comment: `onPostExecute` executes in the main thread, so you cannot do connections there. That's the purpose of the `doInBackground` part.

Comment: but when I use thread or coroutine or async so it used to take bit time so my if else condition failing because I'm checking item is exists or not in db if exists so not store the value if not exists then store the value in DB. how can I get rid from this issue?

Answer (score 0):

All the tasks like loading content from internet, fetching data from storage has to be done in AsyncTask rather than doing on the UI thread.

Create a class

```
public class MyCLass extends AsyncTask
```

You can create a function to access the database in this class. In the UI thread, create a object of that class and call that function you have created. There r many tutorials available on the internet for AsyncTask.